# c++ error, "could not deduce argument for 'std..."

Tags: c++

i keep getting the same errors on my program, any help would be greatly appreciated.

> Error 1   error C2784: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>
>   &std::getline(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>
>   &,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce
>   template argument for 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &' from
>   'char'    c:\Users\esmier\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Chapter 4
>   lab\Chapter 4 lab\source.cpp  40  Chapter 4 lab
>
> Error 2   error C2780: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>
>   &std::getline(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>
>   &,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const _Elem)' : expects 3
>   arguments - 2 provided    c:\Users\esmier\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2008\Projects\Chapter 4 lab\Chapter 4 lab\source.cpp  40  Chapter 4 lab

there errors also happen in the section commented as case b

```
#include <iostream>
#include<sstream>
int main()
{
double hours;
double Package_A_price=9.95, Package_A_hours=10, Package_A_additional=2.00,Package_A_total;
double Package_B_price=14.95, Package_B_hours=20, Package_B_additional=1.00,Package_B_total;
double Package_C_price=19.95;
char package_choice, additional_hours[3];

//table output

cout<<"Please choose your package below";

cout<<"Package A:\t"<<"For $9.95 per month 10 hours of service are provided.\n";
cout<<"\t\tAdditional hours are $2.00 per hour\n\n";

cout<<"Package B:\t"<<"For $14.95 per month 20 hours of service are provided.\n";
cout<<"\t\tAdditional hours are $1.00 per hour\n\n";

cout<<"Package A:\t"<<"For $19.95 per month unlimited access is provided.\n\n\n";

cout<<"What is your package letter?\n";
cin>>package_choice;
while (package_choice!='A'||'a'||'B'||'b'||'C'||'c')
{
    cout<<"You entered an incorrect option.\n";
    cout<<"please reenter your choice.\n\n";
}
switch (package_choice)
{
//package A choice
case 'A||a':
    cout<<"Did you have any additional hours?\n";
    getline(cin, additional_hours);
    if (additional_hours == 'yes')
    {
        cout<<"How many hours did you have?\n";
        cin>>hours;
        while (hours >744)
        {
            cout<<"You can not have over 744 hours per month!\n";
            cout<<"Time is a linear constant, Please renter your amount.\n";
        }
        Package_A_total=9.95+(2.00*hours);
        cout<<"Your Total for Package A is $"<<Package_A_total;
        break;
    }
//package B choice
case 'B||b':
    cout<<"Did you have any additional hours?\n";
    getline(cin, additional_hours);
    if (additional_hours == 'yes')
    {
        cout<<"How many hours did you have?\n";
        cin>>hours;
        while (hours >744)
        {
            cout<<"You can not have over 744 hours per month!\n";
            cout<<"Time is a linear constant, Please renter your amount.\n";
        }
        Package_B_total=14.95+(1.00*hours);
        cout<<"Your Total for Package B is $"<<Package_B_total;
        break;
    }
//package C choice
case 'C||c':
    cout<<"Your Total for Package C is $"<<Package_B_price;
    break;

default: cout<<"You did not Enter A B or C.\n";
         cout<<"Please reenter your choice.";
}



system ("pause");
    return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 5):

`additional_hours` is declared as <s>a character</s> an array of 3 characters. This form of getline expects you to use std::string (another form that is for C-style `char*` is the member function of cin).

There are numerous other errors, apparently from you not knowing that **char** means a single character:

```
case 'A||a':
if (additional_hours == 'yes')
```

Those use multibyte character constants. Basically it just doesn't mean what you expect at all (it is a single number encoded in ASCII characters or something like that).

```
while (package_choice!='A','a','B','b','C','c')
```

Again this is not how you compare multiple conditions, which you need to combine with logical and and or (&& and ||). As it is, it uses the comma operator which means evaluate all operands and use the last ('c') as the result.

Also, the tolower or toupper function in `<cctype>` might help you.

Turning on compiler warnings (-Wall with GCC) might reveal all these errors: [Warning] multi-character character constant, [Warning] left-hand operand of comma has no effect, [Warning] case label value exceeds maximum value for type, [Warning] comparison is always false due to limited range of data type.

Edit: Now that you've declared `additional_hours` as an array of chars, you should be aware that 3 characters is not enough to store the string "yes" because there is no room for the null-terminator. You would be best off using std::string class.

Comment: additional hours is defined to take 3 letters if you look at the variable description

Comment: Fixed that. However, asker edited the original code: char package_choice, additional_hours(3);

Answer (score 0):

I see one flaw already your while loop doesnt reset the package_choice:

```
while (package_choice!='A','a','B','b','C','c'){       
         cout<<"You entered an incorrect option.\n";        
         cout<<"please reenter your choice.\n\n";
}
```

You need to cin >> the package choice again.

Comment: in a while loop the variable can be before the statement

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that it likes what you're passing in to getline.  Try declaring additional_hours as an `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::cout` or `std::cin` or `std::cin.getline(..)` instead of what you are using.

Use `std::cin.get()` instead of `system("pause")` to hold your screen

Comment: or simply add "using namespace std;" before your main function because the all the global identifiers of Standard C++ Library are defined in the namespace "std"

Comment: yes sorry using namespace std; is there i just failed to copy it

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
cin.getline(additional_hour, 3)
```